# Token Exchange Error: 'invalid_client' When Exchanging Firebase ID Token for Google Access Token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-api

**Question**:
I'm trying to exchange a Firebase ID token for a Google Access Token on my server, but I keep encountering the "invalid_client" error. I've checked and double-checked my configuration, but I'm unable to resolve this issue. Can someone please help me troubleshoot and find a solution?

**note:** I am usign firebase methode signInWithEmailAndPassword and it's return Id token we are work with this token.  rcv in server side

Here are the relevant details:

- I'm using a service account for server-to-server authentication.
- I've created an OAuth 2.0 client ID in my Google Cloud project.
- My scopes and API configurations seem correct.
- I've carefully reviewed my server code for typos and errors.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  // databaseURL: "https://fir-authcalendertest-4ca25-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
});
 app.post("/exchange-token", async (req, res) => {
  const { firebaseIdToken } = req.body;

  try {
    // Verify the Firebase ID token
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(firebaseIdToken);
    console.log(decodedToken);

    // Perform the token exchange
    const response = await axios.post("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
      grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
      assertion: firebaseIdToken,
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    });

    const googleAccessToken = response.data.access_token;

    // Use the Google Access Token for the Google Calendar API or other Google services
    // ...

    res.status(200).json({ googleAccessToken });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(
      "Token exchange error:",
      error.response ? error.response.data : error.message
    );
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Token exchange failed" });
  }
});
```

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on what might be causing the "invalid_client" error and how to resolve it. Thank you in advance for your help!

**Title: "Token Exchange Error: 'invalid_client' When Exchanging Firebase ID Token for Google Access Token"**

**Question:**
I'm encountering a persistent issue with the "invalid_client" error when attempting to exchange a Firebase ID token for a Google Access Token on my server. Despite extensive troubleshooting, the problem persists. Here are the steps I've taken, expected results, and actual outcomes:

**note:** I am usign firebase methode signInWithEmailAndPassword and it's return Id token we are work with this token.  rcv in server side

**What I've Tried:**

1. I've created a Google Cloud project with a correctly configured OAuth 2.0 client ID.
2. My server uses a service account for server-to-server authentication, and the service account has been granted the necessary permissions in my project.
3. I've reviewed the scopes and API configurations in both the client and server code to ensure they match.
4. I've carefully reviewed my server code for typos and errors in the request to the token exchange endpoint.
5. I've checked my network and firewall settings to ensure they're not blocking outbound requests.

**What I Expected:**
I expected that the exchange of a Firebase ID token for a Google Access Token would be successful. The "invalid_client" error should not occur, and the Google Access Token should be returned as a valid response.

**What Actually Resulted:**
Despite my efforts, I consistently receive the "invalid_client" error, and the Google Access Token is not successfully exchanged or returned. I've reviewed error logs, examined both client and server configurations, and even attempted the request using tools like cURL. However, the issue remains unresolved.

I'm seeking advice and insights from the community on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Firebase and Google Cloud use different OAuth 2 Identity Providers. That is the error **invalid_client**. In other words, you cannot exchange an Identity Token from Firebase for a Google Cloud Access Token. Identity Tokens provide identity (email address), and Access Tokens contain permissions. Generate the access token directly: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#generate_an_access_token

Comment: thank you for your valuable response 

Comment: This may help too: https://medium.com/@mulhoon/integrating-google-calendar-with-firebase-a-step-by-step-guide-d28ab68097b9